# Parsing date/timestamp from VBO file with NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, vbo, vbox

Im trying to figure out this timestamp format, but it looks weird to me.

There is a timestamp in that format: 184930.60
Explanation is: "This is UTC time since midnight in the form HH:MM:SS.SS."

It looks like number of seconds (based on change in file, for 20Hz GPS module), but it is 51h when you convert these seconds, and this can't be 51h after midnight.

Any idea how to convert that into nsdate?

Details about file format: https://racelogic.support/01VBOX_Automotive/01General_Information/Knowledge_Base/VBO_file_format

Comment: I think they meant that `184930.60` is 18h 49m 30s (and the rest being 60 fractional seconds). So the dateFormat should be `HHmmss.SS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working example:

```
-(NSDate *)getDateFromDecimalTime:(double)decimalTime{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HHmmss.SS"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", decimalTime]];


    //gather current calendar
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //gather date components from date
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:date];

    // Get current year/day/month
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    // Specify which units we would like to use
    unsigned units = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;
    NSCalendar *calendar2 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar2 components:units fromDate:now];

    //set date components
    [dateComponents setDay:[components day]];
    [dateComponents setMonth:[components month]];
    [dateComponents setYear:[components year]];

    //save date relative from date
    NSDate *completeDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

    return completeDate;
}
```